# How do I get distinct COUNT in dynamic pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a temporay table #reservationWithBranch  contains

```
ScheduleName               UserId   BranchId        BranchCode
NULL                        NULL    1              TVM
XMS DAJ 20 Dec 2014          5      2              EKM
XMS DAJ 20 Dec 2014          5      2              EKM
XMS DAJ 29 Dec 2014          5      2              EKM
XMS DAJ 29 Dec 2014          5      2              EKM
NULL                         2      3              KDK
XMS DAJ 29 Dec 2014          6      3              KDK
XMS DAJ 20 Dec 2014          6      3              KDK
NULL                         8      3              KDK
NULL                         1      15             PLK
NULL                         7      15             PLK
NULL                        NULL    16             KNR
NULL                         9      17             KA
```

The ScheduleName, UserId, BranchId and BranchCode are dynamic i want to get the output as follows

```
SheduleName        TVM  EKM  KDK PLK   KNR   KAK
DAJ 20 Dec 2014     0   2    1    0     0    0
DAJ 29 Dec 2014     0   2    1    0     0    0
```

I tried the following code

```
SELECT * from #reservationWithBranch
--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT ScheduleName, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM #reservationWithBranch
    PIVOT(COUNT(ScheduleName) 
          FOR BranchCode IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'



--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
print @DynamicPivotQuery

DROP TABLE #reservationWithBranch
```

But result is not correct. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I found that you have the same data in your table. Inorder to avoid that and get the actual count, insert to a new table

```
SELECT DISTINCT *,
CASE WHEN ScheduleName IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE COUNT(BranchCode) OVER(PARTITION BY ScheduleName,BranchCode) END CNT 
    INTO #TEMP2
    FROM #TEMP
```

Get the columns

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @Columns2 NVARCHAR (MAX)

SET @cols = SUBSTRING((SELECT DISTINCT ',['+BranchCode+']' FROM #TEMP2 GROUP BY BranchCode FOR XML PATH('')),2,8000)

SET @Columns2 = SUBSTRING((SELECT DISTINCT ',ISNULL(['+BranchCode+'],0) AS ['+BranchCode+']' FROM #TEMP2 GROUP BY BranchCode FOR XML PATH('')),2,8000)
```

Then pivot it dynamically

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT ScheduleName,' + @Columns2 + ' FROM 
             (
                 SELECT ScheduleName,BranchCode,CNT FROM #TEMP2
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 SUM(CNT)
                 FOR [BranchCode] IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            WHERE ScheduleName IS NOT NULL;'



EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Here is your result

[image]

Comment: I have updated the query to get zero instead of NULL. Please check @Riyas K